# In "They Live", could the human collaborators see through the illusions?

Tags: aliens, technology, john-carpenter, they-live

In *They Live*, the world is filled with hidden messages, as well as aliens and alien technology hidden from normal human sight.  The rebels had "Hofmann lenses" available as sunglasses and contact lenses that would allow humans to see through these alien illusions.

The aliens were revealed to have human collaborators.  Were these human collaborators able to see through the illusions, or were they subject to all the same subliminal messages?

Comment: Coincidentally I watched this last weekend.  I don't believe they ever conclusively state it one way or the other in the normal film.  The script/director's cut/Word of God might say otherwise, so I won't answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/they-live-script-transcript-carpenter.html) of the theatrical version (see @IanPugsley 's comment on the question above), it seems the human power elite knew the aliens' origins but not their appearance. Even when they are out of sight of regular humans, they're never shown wearing anything other than human clothing.

Arguing the point again from logic, it makes no sense to make the collaborators aware of the illusion -- quite apart from the aliens' appearance putting them off, they would quickly become bored to the point of insanity having to deal with all the content-free billboards, TV shows, magazines and books.